# How do I add tap event for a table cell in Sencha Touch?

Tags: data-binding, sencha-touch

I have a dataView where I am binding data to a table. This is a complex data where I have to bind click event for each table cell too. I do not have any idea how this could be done in Sencha Touch, but the same has been done with jQuery and jQMobile.

Here is my code.

```
var touchTeam = Ext.create('Ext.DataView', {
        fullscreen: true,
        items:[{
            xtype:'toolbar',
            title:'Dashboard',
            docked:'top',
            items:[{
                iconCls:'home',
                iconMask:true,
                ui:'confirm'
            },{
                xtype:'spacer'
            },{
                xtype:'button',
                text:'Logout',
                ui:'decline',
                handler:function(){
                    Ext.Msg.confirm('ALERT','Are you sure that you want to logout?',Ext.emptyFn);
                }
            }]
        },{
            xtype:'toolbar',
            docked:'bottom'
        }],
        store: {
            fields: ['AAAA', 'BBBB', 'CCCC', 'DDDD', 'EEEE'],
            data: [
                {AAAA: 'TableRow1',  BBBB: 0,CCCC:4,DDDD:2,EEEE:0},
                {AAAA: 'TableRow2',  BBBB: 0,CCCC:0,DDDD:0,EEEE:0},
                {AAAA: 'TableRow3',  BBBB: 0,CCCC:0,DDDD:0,EEEE:0},
                {AAAA: 'TableRow4',  BBBB: 0,CCCC:0,DDDD:0,EEEE:0},
            ]
        },
        itemTpl:'<table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" style="width:100%; margin-top:10px;"><tr><td style="width:20%; text-align: center;">{AAAA}</td><td style="width:20%; text-align: center;">{BBBB}</td><td style="width:20%; text-align: center;">{CCCC}</td><td style="width:20%; text-align: center;">{DDDD}</td><td style="width:20%; text-align: center;">{EEEE}</td></tr></table>'
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach a "[itemtap](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.DataView-event-itemtap)" listener to the Dataview. And inside the function you have to check the target element.

```
listeners : {
    scope : this,
    itemtap : function(dataview, index, el, record, e){
        //Browser event e
        console.log(e.target, el);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it works. But do I have any option to select an attribute of the tapped element? E.g. I have a rowid with the <td> so how do I select the id? jQuery: '$("td #cellID").attr(rowid)'.

Comment: You can check e.target element and Ext.get(e.target).getAttribute('id'); will give you the id of the component. Do check the Element class in Sencha API docs.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Do we have any grid available in Sencha Touch 2? Can I get the same results when used on a grid?

Comment: Yes, there is Simoens's Sencha Touch 2.0 grid component. Check the component here : https://github.com/mitchellsimoens/Ext.ux.touch.grid

Comment: And this is also a Dataview component, so you should get the same result.

Comment: How do i get the innerHTML of the selected cell?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using javascript you can do it in `<td>` by adding this

```
'<td class="width" style="color:black;" onClick="javascript:nameTaps">{Name}</td>',
```

Comment: But on click of the cell I need to display another set of data corresponding to the cell clicked. How do I get this done if I use your method?

Comment: for that you need to pass parameters like onClick="javascript:NameTap(\'{Name}\',{ID})"

Comment: Thanks Nag will try out for sure.